# Grails Searchable Plugin - No entities listed to be indexed

Tags: grails, lucene, grails-plugin, searchable

I am using the Searchable Plugin 0.6.4 in a Grails 2.2.3 application, but I am encountering a strange error. The error says: `GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: No entities listed to be indexed, have you defined your entities correctly?`

I only have one class listed to be indexed. Below is that class (simplified a bit):

```
class Incident {

    String howReceived
    Date timeOfCall
    Date timeOfArrival

    User reportingOfficer

    static searchable = [ except: ['version', 'dateCreated', 'lastUpdated'] ]

    static embedded = [ 'witnesses' ]
    static hasMany = [ witnesses: Witness ]

    static mapping = {
        datasource 'police'
        table 'incidents'
    }
}
```

That's all I have, a simple mapping. Below I've also included my stack trace and debug statements I turned on.

***Edit***: It appears that for some reason the `sessionFactory` bean is not finding any class meta data in the `DefaultHibernateEntitiesLocator` class. So...

```
Map allClassMetaData = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
assert allClassMetaData == null
```

Not sure why or if that information helps.

**Debugging**

```
searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin Not found: Searchable
searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin Trying to load config from 'SearchableConfiguration.class'
searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin Not found: SearchableConfiguration
searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin Defining Compass and Compass::GPS beans
searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin Done defining Compass and Compass::GPS beans
spring.DefaultSearchableCompassFactoryBean Building SearchableCompassFactoryBean with grailsApplication [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication@10fdea05] and compassClassMappingXmlBuilder [grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder@e0ef6fa]
spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean Building new Compass
config.EnvironmentSearchableCompassConfigurator Setting Compass connection to [/Users/grantmcconnaughey/.grails/projects/campus-police/searchable-index/development]
config.DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator Mapping class [com.company.police.Incident] with strategy [searchable class property]
config.DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator No mapping strategy found for class [com.company.police.Employee]: assuming this class is not searchable
mapping.SearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassMappingUtils Mapping [Incident.howReceived]
mapping.SearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassMappingUtils Mapping [Incident.id]
mapping.SearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassMappingUtils Mapping [Incident.timeOfArrival]
mapping.SearchableGrailsDomainClassCompassMappingUtils Mapping [Incident.timeOfCall]
mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder Building Compass mapping XML for [com.company.police.Incident] from description [CompassClassMapping: mappedClass=[class com.company.police.Incident],  mappedClassSuperClass=[null], alias=[Incident], spellCheck=[null], subIndex=[null], root=[true], poly=[false], extend=[null], propertyMappings=[[CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[domestic], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[hateCrime], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[howReceived], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[id], propertyName=[id], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[occurredFrom], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[occurredTo], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[officerAssaulted], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[officerKilled], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[readyForSignature], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[reportNumber], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[timeOfArrival], attributes=[{}], CompassClassPropertyMapping: type=[property], propertyName=[timeOfCall], attributes=[{}]]]]
mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder Mapping Searchable Property 'com.company.police.Incident.howReceived' with property attributes [name:howReceived] and meta-data [howReceived:[:]]
mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder Mapping Searchable Property 'com.company.police.Incident.timeOfArrival' with property attributes [name:timeOfArrival] and meta-data [timeOfArrival:[:]]
mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder Mapping Searchable Property 'com.company.police.Incident.timeOfCall' with property attributes [name:timeOfCall] and meta-data [timeOfCall:[:]]
mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder com.company.police.Incident xml [<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE compass-core-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Compass/Compass Core Mapping DTD 2.0//EN"
    "http://www.compass-project.org/dtd/compass-core-mapping-2.2.dtd">
<compass-core-mapping>
  <class name='com.company.police.Incident' alias='Incident' root='true' poly='false' support-unmarshall='true'>
    <id name='id' />
    <property name='howReceived'>
      <meta-data>howReceived</meta-data>
    </property>
    <property name='timeOfArrival'>
      <meta-data>timeOfArrival</meta-data>
    </property>
    <property name='timeOfCall'>
      <meta-data>timeOfCall</meta-data>
    </property>
  </class>
</compass-core-mapping>]
mapping.SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator Adding [com.company.police.Incident] mapping to CompassConfiguration
spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean Done building Compass
domain.DynamicDomainMethodUtils Adding searchable methods to [com.company.police.Incident]
searchable.SearchableGrailsPlugin Started Compass::GPS
compass.CompassGpsUtils Starting Searchable Plugin bulk index
```

**Stacktrace**

```
context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: No entities listed to be indexed, have you defined your entities correctly?
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No entities listed to be indexed, have you defined your entities correctly?
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.performIndex(ConcurrentParallelIndexExecutor.java:88)
    at org.compass.gps.device.support.parallel.AbstractParallelGpsDevice.index(AbstractParallelGpsDevice.java:119)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.DefaultReplaceIndexCallback.buildIndexIfNeeded(DefaultReplaceIndexCallback.java:42)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager$ReplaceIndexOperationCallback.firstStep(DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.java:281)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.doOperate(DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.java:218)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.doReplaceIndex(DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.java:266)
    at org.compass.core.lucene.engine.manager.DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.replaceIndex(DefaultLuceneSearchEngineIndexManager.java:261)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps.doIndex(SingleCompassGps.java:118)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.AbstractCompassGps.index(AbstractCompassGps.java:154)
    at org.compass.gps.impl.AbstractCompassGps.index(AbstractCompassGps.java:128)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.CompassGpsUtils.index(CompassGpsUtils.java:49)
```

Comment: 2 things you may want to check: 1. 'grails clean' (with fingers crossed :) ) and 2. check permissions on the folder where the indexes are stored

Comment: Thanks, @aldrin. I've done a grails clean several times with no luck. I also checked the permissions on the folder where indexes are stored, and it is writing to that folder so I don't think that is an issue. It is creating a `gpsindex` and an `index` folder. Inside of those folders there is an `incident` folder that has the files `segments_1` and `segments.gen`. So It looks like rights is not an issue. :(

Comment: if you could share your app code somewhere(or a sample that has this error), maybe someone can take a look. there is nothing obviously wrong with your code, must be some setup/config issue

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have any configuration. I just took the default config. And the error occurs when I run `grails run-app`, not around any particular code that I have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was using a dataSource with a non-default name, in this case 'police'. I haven't seen anywhere in the doc that mentions the plugin will not work with a dataSource with a different name than simply "dataSource". I will try to update their doc soon.

I found the fix [here](http://mydigitalbricks.blogspot.com/2012/02/searching-multiple-data-sources-in.html). In case that link goes down, here's what you do. Add the following to `resources.groovy`:

```
import org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice
import grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.SessionFactoryLookup

beans = {
    compassGpsDevice(HibernateGpsDevice) { bean ->
        bean.destroyMethod = "stop"
        name = "hibernate"
        sessionFactory = { SessionFactoryLookup sfl ->
          sessionFactory = ref('sessionFactory_datasourceName') 
        }
        fetchCount = 5000
    }
}
```

To add other dataSources with indexable classes, add the following:

```
anotherUniquecompassGpsDevice(HibernateGpsDevice) { bean ->
    bean.destroyMethod = "stop"
    name = "unqiueHibernateName"
    sessionFactory = { SessionFactoryLookup sfl ->
        sessionFactory = ref('sessionFactory_uniquedatasource') 
    }
    fetchCount = 5000
  }
```

And finally add...

```
import org.compass.gps.impl.SingleCompassGps

compassGps(SingleCompassGps) {
    compass = ref('compass')
    gpsDevices = [compassGpsDevice, anotherUniqueCompassGpsDevice]
}
```